# How to exclude columns with only missing values from plot loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have a dataset with over 100 columns of data which can change each week. To measure the data for odd values I made a loop that plots each column of data.

```
invisible(lapply(colnames(Data), function(x) { 
    plot(Data[,x], main=x, type="b", xlab= 'Week', ylab='Amount')
    abline(h=1.2*(mean(Data[,x], na.rm=TRUE, trim=0.05)), col="red") 
    abline(h=.8*(mean(Data[,x], na.rm=TRUE, trim=0.05)), col="red") 
}))
```

Since other people that are not familiar with R also need to use the script, I am making one that should be always working, even if the data is changing. The data is being refreshed each week so to make sure that the loop is working at e.g. the beginning of the year, I need to build in a way in the loop that deals with columns that do not have any data yet. So my question is, how do I build in a way that columns with only missing values are not messing up my script.

Comment: if number of is.na values is equal to the column length, then exclude it!

Answer (score 0):

You could check first for columns that contain only missing values with smth like:
`all_missing <- sapply(colnames(Data), function(x) all(is.na(x)))`
and then exclude them from further plotting functions
`plot_data <- Data[ , -which(all_missing)]`
hth